# get data from object - i see the data but cant save them

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you can see, I'm new here - I realy tried to search, but didn't find something to solve my problem.

so here is my problem.
if I do this:

`console.log($("#grid").data("kendoGrid")._data);`

This shows in the console like this:

[image]

So I understand this:
There is an Array with an Object with data. I need, what is in *Description* --> the "sd" but i can't get access to it.

so, i tried to get the data from description like this:

`console.log($("#grid").data("kendoGrid")._data[0].toString(Description));`

This shows in the console like this:

[image]

Then i tried to get access with this

`console.log(JSON.stringify($("#grid").data("kendoGrid")._data[0].Description));`

This shows in the console like this:

[image]

What I need is the "sd" from the first picture.

UPDATE:

here is the output from `JSON.stringify($("#grid").data("kendoGrid")._data[0]`

[image: console ouput]

and if i do this without stringify, there is just a freespace in the console.log :-/

Comment: Show us what `JSON.stringify($("#grid").data("kendoGrid")._data[0]` produces. What you want is `$("#grid").data("kendoGrid")._data[0].Description` without stringify

Comment: without stringify, there is just a blank line in the console - no input like the "sd" which i searched and need :(

Comment: can you show us the JSON string

Comment: Ok...that means you are trying to access that array or object before it is populated. What you were seeing  in console is a live object not a snapshot

Comment: ah ok, this could be.
is there a way, to get access to it? or do i have to store it?

@Mohamed SaȜed it is shown in the last picture

Comment: Can you again store that stringify data in a variable and parse it ?

Comment: when i store it in an new variable, the "description" is empty.
I think it is how @charlietfl told it above. but i dind't figured out, how to populate it^^
when I solve my problem, i will update this here :-)