# Get data from live object

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

Here is my situation:
I got a Webclient, in this Webclient is an input field. 
What I need, is to get the live data from this input.

I need that string in **`Description`** which is **`sd`**.

```
console.log($("#grid").data("kendoGrid")._data);
```

And this show me what I want to see:

[image: data in object, what I need]

But I cant get Access to it.
Someone told me this:

> You are trying to access that array or object before it is populated. What you were seeing in console is a live object not a snapshot.

But I still don't know how to access them.

Yes I did searching, but I didn't find anything.

I know, I need to store the **`sd`**, but really don't know how.

Here is my previous question: [get data from object - i see the data but cant save them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48404011/9256975)
.

Can anyone help me?

Best regards.

Comment: If you're getting it with an asynchronous function, you need to access the field in the callback.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-undefined-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron?newsletter=1&nlcode=97716%7c4ba7

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
console.log($("#grid").data("kendoGrid")._data[0].Description);
```

Comment: tried it, but didn't work - if I do that there comes a blank field - no entry.

Comment: My method is correct, however i think you try to access your object before created it, so you have a blank field